# Как задать margins элемента в процентах, но равными с разных сторон?

Tags: вёрстка, css

Есть элемент который должен отстоять от контейнера на равные расстояния со всех сторон. Однако проблема в том, что эти расстояния не должны быть фиксированными, поэтому я не могу задать одинаковый отступ в пикселях, все должно масштабироваться. Если же я задам отступы в процентах, то они разумеется будут разными, т.к. процент по вертикали не равен проценту по горизонтали. Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

[Слой по центру веб-страницы](http://htmlbook.ru/layout/sloy-po-tsentru-veb-stranitsy)

Comment: Спасибо, отличная идея, но я не могу фиксированно задать размеры слоя, мне надо чтобы и он, и его margins уменьшались при уменьшении документа.

Comment: тогда вычисляйте размер текущего окна при ресайзе с помощью JavaScript